# How do I get the file name from HTTP header while downloading a file with Grails rest plugin?

Tags: rest, http, grails

I am using Grails Rest plugin to download a file from a server but how can I get hold of the suggested file name that is part of the http header field "Content-disposition"?

My code:

```
withHttp(uri:uri){
   def logo = new Logo()
   def status = get(path:path, query:[identity: identity]){ resp, body ->
       if( resp.status == 200){
           logo.contentType = resp.contentType
           // logo.fileName =  How?
           logo.bytes = body.getBytes()
       }
       return resp.status
   }
   if(status == 200){
       return logo
   }
   else{
       log.warn("Failed to fetch logo ")
       return null;
   }
}
```

I can read the content type, byt how do I get the suggested file name?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out one way of doing it. Maybe not the nicest solution but it works for the most common scenarios.

EDIT: I have changed this code to use existing methods to parse elements and properties of a header value. Hopefully it will handle different header scenarios better. I am still not sure if the *filename parameter is handled correctly.

```
withHttp(uri:uri){
   def logo = new Logo()
   def status = get(path:path, query:[identity: identity]){ resp, body ->
       if( resp.status == 200){
           logo.contentType = resp.contentType
           def contentDisposition = resp.getFirstHeader('Content-Disposition')
           def element = contentDisposition?.elements.find{ it.name.equalsIgnoreCase('filename') || it.getParameterByName('filename')}
           if(element)
               logo.fileName = element.getParameterByName('filename')?.value ?: element.value  
           logo.bytes = body.getBytes()
       }
       return resp.status
   }
   if(status == 200){
       return logo
   }
   else{
       log.warn("Failed to fetch logo ")
       return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, this code will break for many valid field values.. See RFC 6266.

Comment: That is true. It does not handle the filename* parameter or a filename where there are escaped quotes. It works for me because I use it in a controlled environment. I will add a note about that. Please post a better answer if you have one.

Comment: I have changed the code above. Hopefylly it handles the RFC better. I will not accept by own answer until I get at least one up-vote. Maybe someone have a better solution?